# Why these 2 simple codes give different results

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, initialization, implicit-conversion

Code 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
   
//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int a[10][10];
  int *p;
  p=a;
  int temp;
  for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
    scanf("%d",(p+j));
  }
  for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
      if(k>j){
        temp = a[j][k];
        a[j][k] = a[k][j];
        a[k][j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
  printf("%d ",*(p+j));
  return 0;
}
```

Code 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int a[3][3];
  int *p;
  p=a;
  int temp;
  for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
    scanf("%d",(p+j));
  }
  for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
      if(k>j){
        temp = a[j][k];
        a[j][k] = a[k][j];
        a[k][j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
  printf("%d ",*(p+j));
  return 0;
}
```

Why changing the array range gave different results? I am transposing the matrix in these codes. My inputs are `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
The output for 1st code is not giving transpose but the output of 2nd code is giving correct result that is `1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9` respectively.

Comment: Because an array of the shape `int a[10][10];` is laid out differently in memory than you expect with your "flat" indexing (`p + j`).

Comment: The variable `a` is an array *of arrays*. In the first case it's an array of ten elements, where each element is an array of *ten* elements of `int`. There are a total of `100` single `int` elements. You fill up the first nine elements of `a[0]` only, the rest stays uninitialized with indeterminate values.

Comment: Also the assignment `p = a` breaks strict aliasing, because `a` is not a pointer to `int`. `a` will *decay* to a pointer to its first element, and as each element is an array you get a pointer to an array (e.g. `a` is the same as `&a[0]` which have the type `int (*)[10]` or `int (*)[3]` in respective code snippet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory layout of `a[3][3]` is:

```
low address     ----------------------------->    high address
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2] [1][0] [1][1] [1][2] [3][0] [3][1] [3][2]
```

while `a[10][10]` layout is thus

```
low address     ------------------------------->    high address
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2] [0][3] [0][4]...[9][6] [9][7] [9][8] [9][9]
```

Your input and output loops index the array from *low address* accessing the first 9 elements, for `a[10][10]` that is: `a[0][0]` to `a[0][8]` - the first 9 elements of row zero, which are not the elements the transposition works on (which is the first three elements of the first three rows).

To look at it another way, for the 10x10 array:

```
// Referenced in the transposition
   0123456789
0: ###.......
1: ###.......
2: ###.......
3: ..........
4: ..........
5: ..........
6: ..........
7: ..........
8: ..........
9: ..........

// Referenced in the input/output:
   0123456789
0: #########.
1: ..........
2: ..........
3: ..........
4: ..........
5: ..........
6: ..........
7: ..........
8: ..........
9: ..........
```

Either (the obvious and intuitive):

```
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", a[i][j] ) ; 
    }
}
```

or (the frankly bizarre and ill-advised):

```
for( int j = 0; j < 9; j++ )
{
    scanf( "%d", p +                         // Low address +
                 ((j / 3) * sizeof(*a) +     // row offset +
                 (j % 3)  ) ;                // column
}
```

and similarly for the output loop.

Note that `p` is redundant.  You could equally:

```
(int*)a +                   // Low address +
((j / 3) * sizeof(*a) +     // row offset +
(j % 3)  ) ;                // column
```

but I am not sure it improves the solution much!

Comment: Am I wrong if I write p=a rather than p=(int *)a

Comment: @Prince  Well if your compiler did not at least issue a warning, you have your compiler warning level set too permissive I'd say.  Either cast it or `int* p = &(a[0][0]) ;`  or `int* p = *a;`.  The cast is probably the least "obscure".

Comment: ... also don't leave a pointer dangling unnecessarily, initialise on declaration:  `int* p = (int*)a ;` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the compiler should issue a message for this code snippet

```
int *p;
p=a;
```

because the types of the left operand and the right operand of the assignment statement are different and there is no implicit conversion from one to another. That is the left operand has the type `int *` while the right operand has the type `int ( * )[10]` due to the implicit conversion of the array designator `a` to a pointer to its first element.

You have to write

```
p = ( int * )a;
```

So the pointer p points to the first element of the first "row" of the two dimensional array `a` and this loop fills 9 elements of the first "row".

```
for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
  scanf("%d",(p+j));
}
```

In fact this loop is doing the same as the following loop

```
for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
  scanf("%d", a[0] + j);
}
```

All other elements have indeterminate values.

In the second case the two-dimensional array has exactly 9 elements of the type `int`.

So the corresponding loop fills with values all elements of the array.

```
for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
  scanf("%d",(p+j));
}
```